# Location updates in background, for only a fixed amout of time?

Tags: ios

Right now, my app is able to receive location updates in the background. However if the user forgets about it, and the app enters background while still receiving updates, it can in theory keep getting updates forever(i think?) until the user correctly turns it off.

Is there a way to set at timer to automatically stop the location manager, in case it is not shut down by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a background task with an expiration. 
Read more about it here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: